# Can we create custom invoice numbers via Xero API

Tags: php, laravel, invoice, accounting, xero-api

We are using Xero for accounting. We started to develop a booking system for our tour company using Laravel Framework.

We can generate an invoice after the booking is added in our new system. The Invoice can be generated for an individual (new customer) or for agent (mass bookings - can include 10 to 100 bookings in one invoice). While the system generates the invoice we would like to create the same invoice in Xero using an API. I am new at this I would appreciate if you can point me to the right direction. So, my questions are:

1- Which API do we need to use to create xero invoices?

Our current Xero invoice fields and the booking system invoice fields are different.
You can see the differences below.

[image]

While I have fields such as Date of Sale,  Booking ID, Guest Name, Tour Name in the invoice that has been generated by the booking system, I have only Description, Quantity and Unit Price fields in the Xero.

2- Can we customize the invoice fields in xero and match them to our booking system?

3- Can we send a custom invoice number when create an invoice via API? I.e. WBS-6YCP2ZF, AATK-1007, MMDR-1008..

4- There is Payment Services section Under the General Settings > Invoice Settings where we can add a payment gateway. Could you please confirm that the option DPS stands for [payment express](http://www.paymentexpress.com)?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to answer your questions below:

1- Which API do we need to use to create xero invoices?

Our current Xero invoice fields and the booking system invoice fields are different.
You can see the differences on this link. While I have fields such as Date of Sale, Booking ID, Guest Name, Tour Name in the invoice that has been generated by booking system, I have only Description, Quantity and Unit Price fields in the Xero.

Answer> You will need to map your current system Invoice fields over to the elements/fields available while creating an invoice in Xero via the Xero API Invoices endpoint here (all the elements available are listed on the endpoint documentation provided).

2- Can we customize the invoice fields in xero and match them to our booking system?

Answer> You can only make use of the elements available via the Invoice endpoint as mentioned above. You cannot add any extra elements/fields that are not available on the endpoint documentation.

3- Can we send a custom invoice number when create an invoice via API? I.e. WBS-6YCP2ZF, AATK-1007, MMDR-1008..

Answer> If you do not specify Invoice number via the API, Xero will auto assign a default Invoice number specified under your Organisations Invoice Settings. You can change the default invoice number sequence as well and the details are on our help center documentation here).

To answer your question, you may specify your won invoice number via the 'InvoiceNumber' element/field available on the Invoice endpoint.

4- There is Payment Services section Under the General Settings > Invoice Settings where we can add a payment gateway. Could you please confirm that the option DPS stands for payment express? 
Answer> As you can see the Merchant FAQ's link listed on our help centre documentation here for DPS takes you to payment express website . To answer your question DPS is Payment express.

I would recommend you to go through out API getting started section here and also our sample SDK libraries available in multiple programming languages here to get familiar with our API.

Hope this helps.

Regards
Krish